# SASL - Plaintext password not accepted - Encrypted works

Tags: postfix, linux-networking, imap, sasl

I have a very strange issue! SASL does not work properly, as it does not accept plain-text passwords (like Outlook sends them)

```
Oct  2 10:35:09 srf cyrus/imap[4119]: accepted connection
Oct  2 10:35:09 srf cyrus/imap[4119]: badlogin: [217.XX.XXX.140] plaintext user@domain.com SASL(-1): generic failure: checkpass failed
```

Now I switch to "Encrypted password" in Thunderbird. I have the same issue as Outlook above on Thunderbird if I turn on "Plain Password"):

```
Oct  2 10:40:40 srf cyrus/imap[14644]: accepted connection
Oct  2 10:40:41 srf cyrus/imap[14622]: login: [217.XX.XXX.140] user@domain.com CRAM-MD5 User logged in
```

Same with Postfix:

Without

```
Oct  2 10:42:48 srf postfix/smtpd[17980]: connect from unknown[217.XX.XXX.140]
Oct  2 10:42:48 srf postfix/smtpd[17980]: warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: Permission denied
Oct  2 10:42:48 srf postfix/smtpd[17980]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Oct  2 10:42:48 srf postfix/smtpd[17980]: warning: unknown[217.XX.XXX.140]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: generic failure
```

With "Encrypted password":

```
Oct  2 10:45:27 srf postfix/smtpd[21872]: connect from unknown[217.XX.XXX.140]
Oct  2 10:45:28 srf postfix/smtpd[21872]: 50B3A332AAB: client=unknown[217.XX.XXX.140], sasl_method=CRAM-MD5, sasl_username=user@domain.com
Oct  2 10:45:28 srf postfix/cleanup[21899]: 50B3A332AAB: message-id=<506FG87C.3080207@domain.com>
Oct  2 10:45:28 srf postfix/qmgr[6181]: 50B3A332AAB: from=<user@domain.com>, size=398, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  2 10:45:28 srf postfix/smtpd[21872]: disconnect from unknown[217.XX.XXX.140]
```

**Config**:

```
/etc/imapd.conf:sasl_mech_list:LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
```

and

```
/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf:mech_list: LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
```

I have no idea where to dig. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

For postfix, the default is to disallow PLAIN AUTH over unencrypted connections.

You really don't want to alter that - either use LOGIN authentication or (better) switch to [**TLS**](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html).